# GOOGLE CHROME: Changing Homepage and Search Engine Settings

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, settings

I need to setup Chrome so that the homepage is that of the schools website and the search engine is that of the schools custom one.

I know I can sign in to all the computers to sync the the homepage and search engine settings.
and I can also go to the Settings and then change it there, but due to the shear number of computers at the school it really an option of last resort.

I have tried:

- Editing the Preference File and Secure Prefrence file
- Editing the Web Data File using SQLLite Browser

However,Chrome, on start-up dismisses the changes I made and restores all the settings to default.

**So my question is...What can I do to automatically change the search engine and homepage without the settings being reverted once Chrome starts up?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try Google Chrome for Work, it allows you to set policies for a wide range of computers 
Link is : https://www.google.com.au/chrome/business/browser/